# How to create a complex type of a existing function?

Tags: c, function, implicit-conversion, complex-numbers

I am just beginning C programming (not C++) and I have to convert the quadratic formula for adressing complex roots, and for printing these. The normal quadratic equation is as follows (for discriminant > 0):

```
else {
        /*  */
        x1 = ((-b) + sqrt(discr)) / (2 * a);
        x2 = ((-b) - sqrt(discr)) / (2 * a);
        printf("%s%.4lf%s%.4lf\n\n", "x1: ", x1, "\tx2: ", x2);
    }
```

When I try to convert this into its complex values I have used the following strategies:

- Creating a new version of the result of the sqrt(discr), the complex part in the equation, by   creating a variable _Complex double discr_complex = discr * I.
  -> OR discr_complex = discr + discr * I.
- Making x1 and x2 complex by 'complex x1' or '_Complex c1' or 'complex x1 = ..formula.. * I' or '_Complex x1 = ...formula * I'.
- Making every part complex by using the keyword complex.

For all these versions it does not print the correct complex output (#+#i). I tried printing the normal values, which works, but not for the complex part. I tried using the methods creal(x1) and cimag(x1) which do not work (undeclared reference to creal / cimag), or x1.real() / x1.imag(), which also doesn't work ('imag' in something not a structure or union).

Does anybody maybe know how to convert my x1 and x2 values into complex numbers, with maybe a clear explanation how to return each seperate part of the complex equation (real/imaginary) and how this conversion takes place taken my 'normal' formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that calling `creal` does not work is that either you have not included the proper header `complex.h` or you are calling it with an argument `x1` that is not of the correct type `double complex`. The second error, when you call `x1.real()` is because the `.` notation tries to access a member of a `struct` but `x1` is a double.

I suggest using `complex.h` that enables working with complex numbers and define a new abc-formula that deals with complex numbers. Also note that you can not use 'regular' math functions like `sqrt` on variables of complex type but need to use the `complex.h` analogs e.g. `csqrt()`

```
#include <complex.h>

int main(void)
{
    double complex z = 1.0 + 0.5 * I;

    printf("The real part of z = %f\n", creal(z));
    printf("The iamginary part of z = %f\n", cimag(z));

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

completely redefine your function, try something like this:

```
void complex_abc() {

    double complex a = 1;
    double complex b = 2;
    double complex c = 3;
    double complex x1;
    double complex x2;
    double complex d;

    d = b*b - 4 * a * c;
    x1 = ( -b + csqrt(d) ) / 2*a;
    x2 = ( -b - csqrt(d) ) / 2*a;

    printf("x1 = %f + i %f\n", creal(x1), cimag(x1));
    printf("x2 = %f + i %f\n", creal(x2), cimag(x2));

    return;
}
```

And as correctly noted by @Lutzl in the comments you need to link the math library with the flag `-lm` during compiling

Comment: OK will try, thanks! P.S. I have added complex.h, should have mentioned! csqrt it is.

Comment: Now it gives 'undefined reference to csqrt'!

Comment: Trying this: else if (discr < 0)
    {
        double complex x3, x4;
        double complex discr_complex = discr*I;
        double complex sqrt_complex = csqrt(discr_complex);
        printf("%f", sqrt_complex);

Comment: Put otherwise: what are the real and imaginary parts in this formula? How should I retype my formula to obtain complexity?

Comment: Still getting the csqrt undefined reference error.. Do you know what it means or what I should adjust? I have #include <complex.h>.

Comment: @user2892481: your status suggests you have not yet read the introductory [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page. Please do so, soon. You haven't formally "accepted" any answer yet.

Comment: @user2892481 that is odd, are you sure that your system has the complex.h header? How do you compile?

Comment: I compile using CodeBlocks with -w -pedantic and -wall, and also tried to use cmd-> gcc -c main interface.c abc.c, the latter of which gives a 'conflicting types' error. I have #include <complex.h> and also now #include <math.h>. I don't know if I don't have complex.h in my system, how do I check this? I installed CodeBlocks MingW version.  @Jongware yes I'll read them now! My apologies.

Comment: I resolved the issue by calculating for the absolute value of the discriminant(- or +) and making that part the imaginary part by adding 'i' on the end when printing, while the normal part is the -b/(2*a), which is correct! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you use complex and math, you need to link the math library, compiler option -lm. Your idea of discr*I is completely ill advised. Of course, your last variant only produces the correct result if discr<0, but that is in all probability the case for the else-branch. Then you can just simply take sqrt(-discr) without absolute value.